# Alphabetically sort with Python?

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

I am aware of the sorted() function but I am having a little trouble using it/implementing it in my code. I have a database containing student records such as Name, address, age etc.  When the user selects "4" the program runs the function to Display all records saved in the database and I desire it to be sorted alphabetically. My function works and displays the records, just not alphabetically. How could I take advantage of the sorted() function to make my code display the records alphabetically? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
rom ShowAllRecords import show_record
from deleteRecord import delete_student
from showRecord import view_records
from createRecord import add_record
global student_info
global database

"""
Fields :- ['Student ID', 'First name', 'Last Name', 'age', 'address', 'phone number']
1. Create a new Record
2. Show a record
3. Delete a record
4. Display All Records.
5. Exit
"""


student_info = ['Student ID', 'First name', 'last name', 'age', 'address', 'phone number']
database = 'file_records.txt'


def display_menu():
    print("**********************************************")
    print("             RECORDS MANAGER    ")
    print("**********************************************")
    print("1. Create a new record. ")
    print("2. Show a record. ")
    print("3. Delete a record. ")
    print("4. Display All Records. ")
    print("5. Exit")


while True:
    display_menu()

    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == '1':
        print('You have chosen "Create a new record."')
        add_record()
    elif choice == '2':
        print('You have chosen "Show a record"')
        show_record()
    elif choice == '3':
        delete_student()
    elif choice == '4':
        print('You have chosen "Display ALL records"')
        view_records()
    else:
        break


print("**********************************************")
print("             RECORDS MANAGER                  ")
print("**********************************************")
```

ViewRecords function-

```
import csv
student_info = ['Student ID', 'First name', 'last name', 'age', 'address', 'phone number']
database = 'file_records.txt'


def view_records():
    global student_info
    global database

    

    print("--- Student Records ---")

    with open(database, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for x in student_info:
            print(x, end='\t |')
        print("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------")

        for row in reader:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end="\t |")
            print("\n")

    input("Press any key to continue")
```

I know I should use the sorted function, just not sure where/how to properly implement it within my code

Sample Run:

> Blockquote

---

```
          RECORDS MANAGER
```

---

```
    1. Create a new record.
    2. Show a record.
    3. Delete a record.
    4. Display All Records.
    5. Exit.
```

Enter your option [1 - 5]: 4
You have chosen "Display ALL records in alphabetical order by last name."
Would you like the registry sorted alphabetically in Ascending or Descending order? (A or D): D

Last Name: Hunt
First Name: Alan
Student ID: 875653
Age: 23
Address: 345 Ocean Way
Phone number: 3334445454

Last Name: Farrow
First Name: Mia
Student ID: 86756475
Age: 22
Address: 34 Lotus Ct
Phone number: 9994448585

Done! Press enter to continue.
returning to Main Menu.

Comment: Which field(s) do you want to sort by? Last name then first name?

Comment: Would you show example records? What IFS(tab or space) does the record use?

Comment: @Stuart I am trying to Show Last name then First name.

Comment: @ConstantinHong I am using tab

Comment: @ConstantinHong Adding a sample run to the main post

Comment: Note that you should provide a [mre] that is _minimal_, so remove everything that isn't relevant to your question. In this case, the only relevant parts are your code for the `view_records` function, and the contents of the CSV file just before you call that function.

Answer (score 0):

You already know you need the `sorted` function. Think about *what* you need to sort: all the records in your csv file, and the *key* to use to sort: Let's say by last name and then first name. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) for more detail on the `key` argument to `sorted`. Since you want to sort by two items, you can create a tuple containing these two items as your key. In this case, for any student record `r`, the last name is the third element (`r[2]`) and the first name is the second element (`r[1]`), so our key needs to be the tuple `(r[2], r[1])`.

In the function where you read the records, instead of printing them immediately, read all the records first, then sort them, and *then* print them:

```
def view_records():
    # These are not necessary since you never set these variables in the function
    # You can access those variables without global
    # global student_info
    # global database

    print("--- Student Records ---")

    with open(database, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        for x in student_info:
            print(x, end='\t |')
        print("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------")

        reader = csv.reader(f)
        student_records = sorted(reader, key=lambda r: (r[2], r[1]))
        for row in student_records:
            print(*row, sep="\t |")

    input("Press any key to continue")
```

Comment: It doesn't let me upvote answers ;p I need atleast 15 reputation to do so

Comment: @Jim I know :) That was general advice for your future participation on SO

Answer (score 0):

By default the `sorted()` function will sort a list alphabetically, so you could read the lines in the file into a list, call sorted on the list, the print that list line by line with something like this:

```
with open(database, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        # make a list of all lines in the database
        line_list = []
        for line in reader:
            line_list.append(line)

        # print the list
        line_list = sorted(line_list)
        for line in line_list:
           print(line)
```

I'm not exactly sure that's the correct way to go line by line for a database file but you get the idea. Another thing you can do with sorted is pass it a function that determines exactly what you sort, so say if you have 3 columns in your database and for each line you split the row into a list of 3 items you could do this:

```
def func(x):
    return x[2]

data = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=func)
```

to sort the data by the third column. This is also used when you want to sort by some manner that's not alphanumeric.

Finally, for questions on basic functions like this I highly recommend [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sorted-function/) as it usually has good basic examples and descriptions of things like this.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the database, you will need to read the whole thing into memory, so I would put that logic in a separate function, returning a list of dicts.

```
def load_records(path, fieldnames):
    with open(database, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return list(csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames))
```

Then call `view_records` with this data as a parameter, and sort the records using a lambda:

```
records = load_records(database, student_info)
view_records(records)

def view_records(records):
    print("--- Student Records ---")
    print(*student_info, sep="\t |")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------")
    for record in sorted(records, key=lambda record: (record["Last Name"], record["First name"])):
        print(*record.values(), sep="\t |")
    input("Press any key to continue")
```

Alternatively, use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as the  key:

```
from operator import itemgetter
...
    for record in sorted(records, key=itemgetter(record, "Last Name", "First name")):
```